# Grails exclude files from compilation

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I exclude certain project groovy files from being compiled and added to a war archive? Maybe it's possible via some configuration in BuildConfig.groovy...

Comment: which version of grails are you using ? grails3 build has move to gradle and you might achieve that with  `sourceSets`

Comment: @FredericHenri, I'm using 2.4.4.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of groovy files?

Comment: @SandeepPoonia, it's just groovy classes, services, domains or whatever...

Comment: @airfix any update here?